# Discord PHP OAUTH - Class not found while there

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0, discord

I'm trying to get a discord authentication working, it seems i've stumbled upon the only usable API on the entire internet for Discord OAUTH. but even that isn't working. (https://github.com/teamreflex/oauth2-discord)

The project requires me to install with composer but even with the correct installed dependencies it still claims dependencies are not correct. a manual install results in errors containing the userclass;

My code;

```
$provider = new \Discord\OAuth\Discord([
    'clientId'     => 'hidden',
    'clientSecret' => 'hidden',
    'redirectUri'  => 'hidden',
]);

$token = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
    'code' => $_GET['code'],
]);

// Get a refresh token
$refresh = $provider->getAccessToken('refresh_token', [
    'refresh_token' => $token->getRefreshToken(),
]);

// Get the user object.
var_dump($provider->getResourceOwner($token));
```

As soon as I set `getResourceOwner()` the script runs into a fatal error:
`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Discord\\OAuth\\Parts\\User' not found in /home/.../discord/Discord.php:108`

I have absolutely no clue how to fix this, and it seems that replies on the git page of this project are answered every few months.

Am I missing something or am I doing something wrong here?
Any case, thank you in advance!

Comment: The error is an autoloading error which is something Composer would normally take care of. If you didn't use Composer (which is what I assume you mean by a manual install), how exactly did you set that up?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant , I downloaded the source and extracted the zip where the vendor dir of league's oauth is. Because composer tells me I need league's oauth v1.3^ when installed the most recent one before trying to install the discord API.

Comment: But if you have composer, why not just use that? Get rid of your manual install and just run `composer require team-reflex/oauth2-discord`. You shouldn't need to manually download anything. It will figure out the versions.

Comment: If you've not used composer before you'll also need to require Composer's autoloader (`require 'vendor/autoload.php';` somewhere as early as possible in your code), see https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: Thanks for your answer @TimFountain!,
This is the output I get when trying to do it with composer; 
https://i.imgur.com/EneVukS.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the repo was out of date,
I was able to successfully run my project after switching to [Moutard3's fork](https://github.com/Moutard3/oauth2-discord).